# Is std::condition_variable::wait() a POSIX thread cancellation point?

Tags: c++, posix

The subject line says it all. My environment is a Linux system with a C++11 compiler.

Anyone know?

Comment: If your threading library implementation uses POSIX threads, and `wait` calls `pthread_cond_wait`, then yes. But I've no idea whether or not it's safe to cancel in a C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course something that is not defined in the standard and as such can not be answered in a cross platform way.

However, if `std::condition_variable::native_handle` is of type `pthread_cond_t*` then you can be relatively sure that `std::condition_variable::wait` will also use `pthread_cond_wait`. Still, there is no guruantee for that so the only safe way is to check your implementation.

In addition, I would restrain from mixing standard tools with platform specific stuff like POSIX. I would either go the full POSIX way or use standard alternatives like boost interruption points.